# Copying in python

Tags: python-3.x, object, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
>>> A = [1,[2,3],4] 
>>> B = A[:]
>>> B[0] = 'x'
>>> B
['x',[2,3],4]
>>>A
[1,[2,3],4]
>>> B[1][0] = 'y'
>>> B
['x',['y',3],4]
>>> A
[1,['y',3],4]
```

At the end when we've asked to return A, we should get [1,[2,3],4] as answer, right? as we have created separate copy for B.

Comment: Because `A[1] and B[1] ` are pointing to the same address when you use `[:]`

Comment: If you want a deepcopy you should use copy.deepcopy. The [:] only makes a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are references by default in python. When you assigned `B = A[:]` you were trying to create a copy of A. It works as you expected for normal values. But second element of A is in turn another List(that is [2,3]), which in turn is another reference.

In other words think of it this way
`B = A[:]`
is like saying

```
B = []
B[0]=A[0] # here A[0] = 1
B[1]=A[1] # here A[1] is a reference to [2,3]
......
```

So in effect the second element of both B and A are a reference to the same List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph

to draw a graph of your data and easily understand the problem: A and B share data.

```
import memory_graph # see install instructions at link above

A = [1,[2,3],4] 
B = A[:]
B[0] = 'x'
print(B)
print(A)
B[1][0] = 'y'
print(B)
print(A)

memory_graph.d() # draw graph
```

[image]

You probably want to make a deep copy instead of a shallow copy:

```
import memory_graph
import copy

A = [1,[2,3],4] 
B = copy.deepcopy(A) # <------ deep copy
B[0] = 'x'
print(B)
print(A)
B[1][0] = 'y'
print(B)
print(A)

memory_graph.d()
```

[image]

See the link above for an explanation of the difference between shallow and deep copy.

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/).